Colored prebreak in listings fails specifically with beamer
I would like to colorize the symbol showing line breaks in code listings (prebreak option of the listings package). I am using pdflatex.
The following code, taken from Colorful prebreak and postbreak tokens with listings package, works using the article class:
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}  % for arrow symbol \Rsh
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=false,
    prebreak=\hbox{\textcolor{gray}{\ensuremath{\Rsh}}}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}[fragile]{}

\begin{lstlisting}
a short command
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
very long command very long command very long command very long command very long command;
\end{lstlisting}

%\end{frame}

\end{document}

Now if you replace the documentclass with beamer, and uncomment the lines for making a frame environment, the compilation fails with:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \kern 
l.4 a 
      short command
?

but it works if I remove the \textcolor command!
So at this point I don't think I can solve this alone... Thanks in advance for your help!

PS: the actual prebreak symbol I wish is an arrow starting from the left and going down, which I can achieve by using the rotatebox from graphicx:
prebreak=\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=bc]{-90}{\textcolor{gray}{\ensuremath{\Rsh}}}}


You can avoid the problem by placing your symbol into a savebox:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox{\quack}
\savebox{\quack}{\hbox{\rotatebox[origin=bc]{-90}{\textcolor{red}{\ensuremath{\Rsh}}}}}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=false,
  rebreak=\usebox{\quack}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{lstlisting}
a short command
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
very long command very long command very long command very long command very long command;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Wow thanks, it works but I have no idea why because I don't know anything about the LaTeX boxes (or is it Tex?) ... Also why does it fail when using beamer? Is it a bug in listings, in xcolor or in beamer?

beamer loads the xxcolor package which adds a \colorlet to an internal xcolor command. This \colorlet command uses in some place the \space command. listings on the other side redefines \space and together this explodes.
Imho the best here would be if xcolor wouldn't use the public \space but an internal command:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}  % for arrow symbol \Rsh
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter %Fix space problem:
\def\XC@space{ }
\def\XC@getclr#1/#2/#3/#4/#5/#6/#7/#8/#9\XC@@
 {\ifcase\XC@@pos\XC@space #1\or#2\or#3\or#4\or#5\or#6\or#7\or#8\fi}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=false,
    prebreak=\hbox{\textcolor{gray}{\ensuremath{\Rsh}}}}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}[fragile]{}

\begin{lstlisting}
a short command
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
very long command very long command very long command very long command very long command;
\end{lstlisting}

%\end{frame}

\end{document}


Thanks for explaining the inner workings!
